# Apache2 server can't find files in same folder

Tags: php, html, apache, server, localhost

Absolute beginner here, correct me if I've done mistakes.

I'm trying to create a login system on an apache2 server (OS: Ubuntu server 20.04 LTE) and I can access all pages from another computer(OS Win10 home) in the same WiFi-net but they won't connect to each other even though they're in the same folder. Chrome says

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.184 Port 80
```

Meaning I can't switch between pages using links nor use a php-file  to handle the form-input. http://ip-adress shows all the avaliable files in /var/www/html but they can't connect to each other.

Opera says above too

Comment: Have you tried to seek your exact WiFi  ip of the computer Apache is running.

Comment: Could we see examples of the exact URLs you are entering, that result in this response? And the file listing Apache presents when you enter just the address? My suspicion is that PHP is not being processed, and file with the **.php** extensions are not being recognized by the web server. Are you sure **mod_php** is installed and configured?

Comment: The URL is simply http://192.168.0.184/form_sub.php . It's of course not accessible outside the WiFi. I'm not sure about mod_php, how do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **mod_rewrite**, To enable run the Following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache2 by the Following command :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```